# glob() function in Perl for getting filenames

Tags: perl, filenames, glob

How can I get the specific name of a file stored in a particular folder using glob() function? I have a sample source code below but having different output, it rather displays the complete path of the file instead of showing only the specific file name. How can I retrieve the file name only from the path set or how can I directly access and get the specific file name? thanks!

```
@files = glob('/Perl/Assignment/*');
foreach $files(@files){
    print "$files\n";
}
```

Output:

```
/Perl/Assignment/file1.txt
/Perl/Assignment/file2.txt
/Perl/Assignment/file3.txt
```

Expected output:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`File::Basename`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Basename):

```
use File::Basename;
my @files = glob('/Perl/Assignment/*');
foreach my $file (@files){
    print basename($file), "\n";
}
```

It's been a part of core Perl for a long time.

(Have to use parens in this case because otherwise it thinks the `"\n"` is an argument to `basename` instead of `print`.)

Comment: how about inserting a specific file name into a database? how can I apply the concept of basename?

Answer (score 3):

If you give `glob` a path then it will return one. You can `chdir` to the directory and specify just the file name pattern, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use constant DIR => '/Perl/Assignment';

chdir DIR;

my @files = glob '*';

say for @files;
```

or, if it is important that the working directory isn't changed then you can localise it using the [`File::chdir`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::chdir) module, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use constant DIR => '/Perl/Assignment';

my @files = do {
    local $CWD = DIR;
    glob '*';
};

say for @files;
```